# How do I close a popup window on a press of a button and initiate postback on the window opening the popup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

see above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like so in button click of the popup

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "auto_refreshparent", @" window.opener.location.reload(); ", true);
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ThatsAllFolks", "window.close();", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to call functions in window.parent.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeThisPopupWindow()
    {
        if (window.parent && window.parent.callBack)
            window.parent.callBack();
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

Obviously you would need to attach the closeThisPopupWindow function to your button.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
parent.document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();; // submit the parent form
self.close(); // close the current window
```

Answer (score 0):

string windowArgs = "toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,width=620,height=500,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,modal=yes";
        string newWindowUrl = "MarketShotPreview.aspx";
        string javaScript =
         "\n" +
         "\n" +
         "\n";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "Popup", javaScript);